# No report was found for sonar.python.coverage.reportPaths using pattern coverage-reports/coverage.xml

Tags: python, jenkins-pipeline

My sonar branch coverage results are not importing into sonarqube.
coverage.xml are generating in jenkins workspace.
following are the below jenkins and error details :
WARN: No report was found for sonar.python.coverage.reportPaths using pattern coverage-reports/coverage.xml

I have tried in my ways but nothing worked.

```
    withSonarQubeEnv('Sonarqube') {
      sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=$USERNAME -Dsonar.password=$PASSWORD -Dsonar.projectKey=${params.PROJECT_KEY} -Dsonar.projectName=${params.PROJECT_NAME} -Dsonar.branch=${params.GIT_BRANCH}  -Dsonar.projectVersion=${params.PROJECT_VERSION} -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.language=${params.LANGUAGE} -Dsonar.python.pylint=${params.PYLINT_PATH} -Dsonar.python.pylint_config=${params.PYLINT} -Dsonar.python.pylint.reportPath=${params.PYLINT_REPORT} -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=${params.ENCODING} -Dsonar.python.xunit.reportPath=${params.NOSE} -Dsonar.python.coverage.reportPaths=${params.COVERAGE}"        
    }
```

I expect my coverage results to reflect on sonar

Answer (score 1):

You are having that error because you are specifying the coverage report path option wrong, and therefore sonar is using the default location `coverage-reports/coverage.xml`.

The correct option is `-Dsonar.python.coverage.reportPath` (in singular).

Comment: It depends which version you use. Since 1.2 reportPaths is correct - https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Python+Coverage+Results+Import

Comment: I have the same problem as OP and singular didn't work for me. It only added another WARN entry saying this.

Answer (score 0):

I still have this problem on Azure Pipelines. Tried many ways without success.

WARN: No report was found for sonar.python.coverage.reportPaths using pattern coverage.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, using GitHub Actions. In my case, only the `reports/coverage.xml` was being made available for sonarcloud Action. I fixed the issue making the whole `reports/` path available, which included the directory `reports/htmlcov`